# Python creating one line statement both if-else condition and for loop with lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, conditional-operator

I'm trying to learn **one line ternary operator** in python3. And also I want to **implement** it to my code to save space.

**My codes are:**

```
if key==i and i not in neighbours: #up there there is an another loop
        if len(j)>1:
            neighbours=[n for n in j]
            print("0", neighbours)
        else:
            neighbours.append(j)
            print("1",neighbours)
```

I'm stuck with if-else and for loop. My codes works but I'm trying to write it in one line.
**You see it also a pseudo code:**

```
if key==i and i not in neighbours: #up there there is an another loop
      {lambda neighbours.append(n): for n in j} if len(j)>1 else neighbours.append(j)
```

For the story:
I have a j values which is a list, if this list's length is greater than 1 I need to append it seperately, if not it is okay just append.

ALL my codes are here if you want to run it:

```
anormal_dict={'1576665': [['02:03:00', '02:28:00'], ['22:28:00', '22:38:00']]}
neighbours = list()
c=""
for key in anormal_dict.keys():
    for i,j in intersection_dict.items():
        if key==i and i not in neighbours:
            if len(j)>1:
                neighbours=[n for n in j]
                print("0", neighbours)
            else:
                neighbours.append(j[0])
                print("1",neighbours)
        if key in j and c not in neighbours:
            findex= j.index(key)-1
            if findex== -1:
                neighbours.append(i)
                print("2", neighbours)

            else:
                c = j[findex]
                neighbours.append(c)
                print("3", neighbours)
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, if `len(j) == 1` you want to append `j[0]` to `neighbours` else append whole list `j`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely there are 2 dictionary. The huge one is named intersection_dict. I'm trying to reshape it according to my conditions.

Comment: Please [edit] a working [mre] of what you want to do - including enought data to see what you do. Your _"all my code"_ has a NameError on `intersection_dict`.

Comment: There are porbably better ways to to what you do using list.extend instead of append or leveragging itertools. With complex conditions there is no sense in using ternary ifs.